# Create a Dynamic PHP Array

Tags: php, database, dynamic, foreach

this might be a bit tricky. First here is my function:

```
public function transfer_smf_userinfo($username)
{
    $sys_columns = implode(', ', $this->_config['bbauth']['columns']['sys']);
    $smf_columns = implode(', ', $this->_config['bbauth']['columns']['smf']);

    $question_marks;

    for($i = 0; $i > sizeof($this->_config['bbauth']['columns']['sys']); $i++)
    {
        if(sizeof($this->_config['bbauth']['columns']['sys']) == $i - 1)
        {
            $question_marks .'?';  
        }
        else {
            $question_marks .'?, ';
        }
    }

    $user = $this->smf_db->query('SELECT '. $smf_columns .' FROM `smf_members` WHERE member_name = ? LIMIT 1', array($username));

    if($user->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $user = $user->row_array();

        $user['register_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user['register_date']);
        $user['last_login'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $user['last_login']);

        $transfer_user = $this->sys_db->query('INSERT INTO `members` ('. $sys_columns .') VALUES ('. $question_marks .')', array());

        if($transfer_user)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**$sys_columns** outputs:

> id, username, password, email, url, avatar, b_date, r_date, l_date

**$smf_columns** outputs:

> id_member, member_name, passwd, email_address, website_url, avatar, birthdate, date_registered, last_login

I need the array at the end of the line on the **$transfer_user** query to have a array like so.

```
array($user['column'], $user['another']);
```

But I need to do it dynamically with each row from **$smf_columns**.

Comment: I could probably rewrite and optimize this into half it's current size **shrugs** Is this a question or a request? What exactly are you asking/requesting?

Comment: I know its not the best right now, I usually code it then recode it once it works in a better way. Just my way of doing it. But I have no clue how to do this part. I just need to be able to do like a foreach inside the **$transfer_user** array with each column from **$smf_columns**

Comment: Something kinda like `
$transfer_user = $this->sys_db->query('INSERT INTO `members` ('. $sys_columns .') VALUES ('. $question_marks .')', array(
 foreach($smf_columns as $column)
 {
  $user[$column] .
 }
));`

Comment: If that's all you want, check my answer. If that's different, comment and I'll try and fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly. Try:

```
$data=array();
foreach($this->_config['bbauth']['columns']['smf'] as $column)
     $data[]=$user[$column];
$transfer_user = $this->sys_db->query(
     'INSERT INTO `members` ('. $sys_columns .') VALUES ('. $question_marks .')',
     $data);
```